# What's the deal with white-space and text-wrap?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've been using `white-space` and was happy with it. Still am. Then, I noticed that there's something called `text-wrap` too. I've seen [somewhere on the internet](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp) that there's no browser support for the latter. However, it's not in the plans for the future nor is it deprecated (let alone obsolete).

So what's that for? Should I regard it in any way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`text-wrap` was originally in [CSS Text level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-text-20120119/#text-wrap). It has since been deferred to [level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-4/#text-wrap). The difference between it and `white-space` is that `white-space` is changed to be a shorthand of two other properties, one of which is `text-wrap`. That's all you need to know for now; any other details are highly subject to change and simply not relevant at this point.

You can disregard `text-wrap` for now. W3Schools is correct in stating that no browser supports it at the moment. You can also continue using `white-space` as normal; its syntax will not change even once the newer version is implemented by browsers.